# CodeIgniter get last username without primary id

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am having a problem with getting the latest username in my database. The database I am having happens to have **no auto_increment id field**. Below is my code:

```
public function _username_check( $user_name )
{

    $this->db->select('user_name');
    $this->db->like('user_name', $user_name);
    $this->db->order_by('user_date');
    $query = $this->db->get('users');


    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    { 


        $row = $query->row();

       $db_username = $row->username;

       echo $db_username;
    }

echo "did not get into the if function";
}
```

I am currently using the **Community Auth** files for my projects. It does not have any auto increment id field so I am using the user_date to check for the last entry.

Somehow it does not go into the if function, am I doing any wrong here?

If user were to enter username, I will need to be able to return username2 and if user were to enter user, I will need to be able to return user3.

Is this the right way to do it?

Any kind souls out there can help me on this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you post your other tables structures so we know it would be safe to do so? Given user_id is not a primary field **(alone)** setting it to auto increment might not be wise specially if it is filled by another table making user_id the foreign key. Or you could easily add a new column like `ts_registered` (DATETIME type) to record when the user was registered and gather last user by that.

Comment: What do you mean by `if user were to enter user, I will need to be able to return user3` ?

Comment: Hi Prix, I have update my question, I have put in my table screenshot, wonder if that is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to add an `additional column` into the user's table with `date time` field. By adding a date time field you can find the latest username while not altering the current db relations.

```
$this->db->select('user_name');
$this->db->like('user_name', $user_name);
$this->db->order_by('user_date','desc');
$this->db->limit(1);   
$query = $this->db->get('users');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. It looks like I have the date column in the database. If that is the case, how can I go about using it?

Comment: then you can order by date column and get by limit

Comment: Hi, I have tried using the method you told me and I have updated my question post. It seems like it will not go into the IF function, is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Thanks! It works! I happened to have missed out the limit query but it works too. Is there any difference if I include or not?

Comment: if not then you will get all the records that match the specified username, in their descending order, since you are only interested in the latest one, providing limit is the good

Comment: I see. Noted on that. Thanks again.